# How to use ingest plugin to import text data?

Tags: elasticsearch, data-ingestion

I am able to import structured data into elasticsearch using logstash and derive reports in Kibana.I went through few articles.But, I am not getting a clear understanding on how do I import text(unstructured data) into elastic search using ingest plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You cant!

elasticsearch API speaks JSON, you cannot upload a text or PDF.

`ingestion pipeline` (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest.html)

> Use an ingest node to pre-process documents before the actual document
>   indexing happens. The ingest node intercepts bulk and index requests,
>   it applies transformations, and it then passes the documents back to
>   the index or bulk APIs.

It works only with document, no raw text.

Comment: Is it true that  without transforming data we cannot directly load data into ES?

Comment: your data must respect ES API (as any other database API), read documentation to find what elasticsearch accepts, this can change with new version.